# SqlDataAdapter.Update (data table) is not working (not updating the database)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows, sqldataadapter

I have the below code where I'm trying to update a database from the c# grid view change made in windows application....

The code is not updating the SQL Server database. I'm not sure where exactly the issue occurs. Everything seems to be fine...

Or is there a way to update the database table using the "update query statement" again the point is how to write the update statement for any value changes in the data grid view ?

I presume there might be an issue with binding and the select command statements...

Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue ?

```
public partial class KnowledgeBaseForm : Form
{
    private SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    private void button_retrievekb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From Table1", con);

            SDA.Fill(DT);

            bindingsource.DataSource = DT;
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingsource;

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                dataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Knowledge Base Rules Found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }   

    private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //binding the datasource with the changes made in the gridview
            bindingsource.DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;
            DT.AcceptChanges();
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);                 
            SDA.Update((DataTable) bindingsource.DataSource);
            MessageBox.Show("Updates successfully submitted to CoSD");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare your DT object in class root like your DataAdapter, and use DT.AcceptChanges  before calling SDA.Update, test it and let us now if it works

Comment: Hi... I have editied the code as what you said... but still didnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class KnowledgeBaseForm : Form
    {
     SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
     DataTable DT = new DataTable();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private void button_retrievekb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

               SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From Table1", con);
               ds = new DataSet();
               SDA.fill(ds,"SomeName");
               dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }

    private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {


            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
               SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);
               SDA.Update(ds,"SomeNme");

            }
          }
    }
```